# Linear algebra- Diagonalization of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

A linear transformation $$ T:R^3→R^3$$ is defined as $$ T:(x)=Cx$$ where $C$ is a symmetric matrix.

a) State the dimensions of the eigenspaces $\mbox{N(C-αI)}$ and $N(c-βI)$

It is also given that: $$C\begin{pmatrix}     -3 \\     
0  \\     
1  \\     
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}     -3α \\     
0  \\     
α  \\     
\end{pmatrix}, C\begin{pmatrix}     -2 \\     
1  \\     
0  \\     
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}     2α \\     
α \\     
0  \\     
\end{pmatrix} $$

**It is given that $C$ has a repeated eigenvalue $α$ and another eigenvalue $β$, where $α \neq β$**

b) Find a basis for $\mbox{N(C-αI)}$ and $N(c-βI)$

→I understand that if $C$ is symmetric then $C$ has to be diagonalisable so that if $α$ is repeated the **algebraic multiplicity= geometric multiplicity= 2**, so $N(C-αI)$ is $2$ dimensional and $N(c-βI)$ is $1$ dimensional.

However, for part b), I don't understand how I would find the bases for the eigenspaces with the information I've been given.

Comment: What is $\beta$?

Comment: I had omitted an important sentence from the question, I added it in bold. Other than that I have no other information.